# Can we tap on an existing place in the google maps in a flutter app and get its detail?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

Can we add a feature in our flutter app where we can tap on the existing places that are shown in the google map can get the details of that place? Instead of adding a custom marker and get the lat long information, I want to display a marker on that particular place and get its detailed info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately no. For some strange reason, the `OnPoiClickListener` hasn't been implemented in the `google_maps_flutter` plugin, although it is available in the native Google Maps SDK (at least on Android).

There is a [feature request on the Flutter Github issues page](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60695), **please go there and upvote the original question** to let the Flutter team know that this feature is needed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Was searching a lot for this feature. So guess, we have to play the waiting game for this one.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why but they haven't implemented it in flutter, i uploaded a repo with changes to make it available (by referencing [matthiasng/plugins@17ea7f3](https://github.com/matthiasng/plugins/commit/17ea7f32b1e7a39c6ee13bf8190b203ed36d32ee)), just add this in your pubspec.yaml

```
  google_maps_flutter:
     git:
       url: https://github.com/riccardo-runci/google_maps_flutter.git
       ref: main
  google_maps_flutter_platform_interface:
      git:
       url: https://github.com/riccardo-runci/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface.git
       ref: main
```

and in the GoogleMap widget

```
   GoogleMap(
      ...
      onPoiTap: (argument) {
         ...
      }
   )
```

it is aligned with the version `2.2.3`